# How to round up a month-date based on certain parameters

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to round up a month-date based on certain parameters. For example: If I have a parameter where if a day in a given month is between the 6th and the 4th of the next month, I need my query to return the next months date. Is there a way to round up the month given these parameters without hard coding case whens for every single month ever?

```
SELECT case when date_trunc('day',li.created_at between '2019-03-06 00:00:00' and '2019-04-06 00:00:00' then '2019-04-01' end) 
FROM line_items li
```

Comment: You could convert the month to a number and add 1. Then use the resulting number to build a new date.

Comment: interesting could you show me an example? I am not quite familiar with this concept

Comment: And what happens on the fifth?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: ELSE date_trunc('month',li,created_at) END. it would just be the regular month

Answer (score 0):

If you want the beginning of the month, but offset by 4 days, you can use `date_trunc()` and subtract some number of days (or add some number of days).  You seem to want something like this:

```
select dateadd(month, 1, date_trunc('month', li.created_at - interval '4 day'))
```

Comment: I get this error message: "Interval values with month or year parts are not supported"

Comment: @spak . . . It seems perverse to support interval literals and to exclude `month` and `year` . . . and not mention it in the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_interval_literals.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a canonical "dates" table that precomputes the mapping from a given date to a new date using your rounding scheme.  The mapping could be done outside of redshift in a script and the table loaded in (or within redshift using a user defined function).